# Determining lowest and highest value from a column in a text file (c++)

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I've been working on this project for a while, or rather, I've been TRYING to figure out how to work on this project for a while. I'm a tremendous newbie in programming in general (probably starting with c++ was a gigantic mistake, but whatever), so keep that in mind.

I have a text file that looks like this: http://pastebin.com/19Bbg1pV

However that is just the tip of the file, the actual file is around 1000 times larger (but shouldn't make a difference, I think).

What I'm asked to do is open the file, and determine what the highest and lowest voltage is, along with the time it occurs (ignore ampere).

How do I do this? I've tried several things, the problem is my time is almost up so I don't have any more time to try stuff around, all I have managed to do so far is read the text file and display it, which is not what I was asked for, but it's the only thing I could grasp regarding streams and opening files.

I'm thinking of purposely dumbing down the assignment and just have a text file with the voltage column and determine lowest and highest value, nothing else.

What I'm trying to do is start reading the first line from voltage, then assign that value to a variable, then read the next line, if the value from that line isn't bigger than the previous one, ignore it, then move to the next line, but if it is bigger, then store that value instead, and move on to the next line, repeat until the end of file. Then simply output whatever is stored in that variable, which should be the largest one.

How do I do this? Please help, I'm starting to lose hope.

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: your logic is fine, Just note you need to have one more variable to find lowest value.you can try your login on small file to cross check you code is working fine.

Comment: Even if your question is off-topic or your problem is resolved: Do not  replace it by "nevermind". You can always vote to delete your question if you don't like it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("test.txt");
    if(!f)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //eat header
    std::string dummy;
    std::getline(f, dummy);

    double time_low = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double volt_low = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double time_high = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    double volt_high = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    double time, volt, amp;

    while(f >> time >> volt >> amp)
    {
        if(volt < volt_low)
        {
            volt_low = volt;
            time_low = time;
        }
        if(volt > volt_high)
        {
            volt_high = volt;
            time_high = time;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6);
    std::cout << " low: " << volt_low << " at " << time_low << "\n";
    std::cout << "high: " << volt_high << " at " << time_high << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this pseudo code helps!

```
f = fopen("your-filename.txt");

min_volt = DBL_MAX;

while (!f.eof())
{
  // fgetline() is a C library function to read a line from the file.
  line = fgetline(f);

  // The function split() takes the line to be splitted and returns
  // the array of strings in the second parameter (here it is tokens).
  // The function returns how many entries are there in tokens.
  num_tokens = split(line, tokens);

  if (num_tokens >= 2)
  {
    // strtod() is a C library function to convert string to double
    time = strtod(tokens[0]);
    voltage = strtod(tokens[1]);
    ampere = strtod(tokens[2]);

    if (voltage < min_volt)
    {
      min_volt = voltage;
      min_time = time;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: These links might be of help as well: 

STL containers and string in c++:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

File handling in c++:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/

Comment: @user3018180: The answer I gave has only pseudo-code. Its not actual C/C++ code. Since its a homework problem, it is your responsibility to write it on your own. Stackoverflow is there to help you to figure out your problems not solve it for you. See here on stackoverflow's policy on homework problems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions